# Tanuki service wrapper logging

Tags: windows, java, logging

I have a question about the Tanuki service wrapper:
My Java application is wrapped in it and I am missing some logging 
when running it with the wrapper.

- Tanuki wrapper version: 3.2.3 (old, I know but it's due to practical reasons)
- Loglevels set to INFO:

```
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO
```

The lines that are missing start with:

```
[main] INFO 
[Thread-7] INFO 
[main] WARN
```

For example this line:
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - ...

They are also not logged in the logfile specified by wrapper.logfile

What can I do to display such lines in the wrapper?